# IBM Data Studio on Red Hat Open Client 6

Tags: linux, eclipse, db2-luw

I am installing IBM Data Studio on RedHat Open Client 6 and getting the following error:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1 /home/XXXX/Downloads/disk1/InstallerImage_linux_x86_64//jre_6.0.0.sr9_20110208_03/jre/bin/java
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
-Xquickstart
-Xgcpolicy:gencon
-jar /home/XXXX/Downloads/disk1/InstallerImage_linux_x86_64/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /home/XXXX/Downloads/disk1/InstallerImage_linux_x86_64/userinst
-name Userinst
--launcher.library /home/XXXX/Downloads/disk1/InstallerImage_linux_x86_64/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813/eclipse_1502.so
-startup /home/XXXX/Downloads/disk1/InstallerImage_linux_x86_64/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 968035
-toolId userinst
-accessRights nonAdmin input @osgi.install.area/install.xml
-vm /home/XXXX/Downloads/disk1/InstallerImage_linux_x86_64//jre_6.0.0.sr9_20110208_03/jre/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
-Xquickstart
-Xgcpolicy:gencon
-jar /home/XXXX/Downloads/disk1/InstallerImage_linux_x86_64/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
```

Please let me know, if I need to change any setting in my machine.

Comment: I'm sure there's a log file or Java core dump somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

I remember there was same case before with installing Data Studio 4.1.1 on a linux.

At that time, the following was the suggestion and I heard it gave relief.
I didn't try this myself. Just try this if it can resolve your case.

```
Adding -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.cairoGraphics=false 
to eclipse.ini
```